# continuity of compositions of functions f and g

Tags: limits, continuity

$f$ and $g$ are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = q$ and $\lim_{x \to q} g(x) = r$.

(a) Give an example to show that it may not be true that $\lim_{x \to p} g(f(x)) = r$.

(b) Show that the result in (a) does occur even if f and g are continuous.

(c) Does the result in (a) hold if f is continuous? How about if only g is continuous?

I came up with an example with $g(x)$ discontinuous for part $(a)$, however I got that $(a)$ doesn't hold if only $f$ is continuous, but holds if $g$ is continuous. My $\epsilon -\delta$ proof for $(c)$ is as follows:

(c) No. $\lim_{x \to p} f(g(x)) \neq r$ if we assume only $f$ is continuous. In fact, we only need $g$ to be continuous, but $f$ can be discontinuous. We want to show given $\epsilon > 0$, $\lvert x - p \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert g(f(x)) - r \rvert < \epsilon$. But $\forall \epsilon>0$, (by $\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = q$), $\exists \delta >0$ such that $\lvert x -p \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) -q \rvert < \epsilon$. This also means $\exists \delta_1 > 0$ (taking $\epsilon = \delta_1$) such that $\lvert g(f(x)) - g(q) \rvert < \epsilon$. Now we must have $g(q) = r$ in order for $\lvert g(f(x)) - r \rvert < \epsilon$. But we didn't need continuity of $f$ at $p$, namely, $f(p) = q$.

So I came up with an example with $g$ discontinuous, but then I proved that the result holds if we assume $g$ is continuous. This doesn't make sense. Is my proof for $(c)$ flawed? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand.  You gave an example that shows that $\lim_{x\to p}g\circ f(x)=r$ if $g$ is continuous, but that the limit may not be $r$ if $g$ is discontinuous.  Is that what you are saying?  Why does that not make sense?

Comment: I have an example that shows lim g(f(x)) is not r if g is discontinuous, but I proved in (c) that g has to be continuous if we want lim g(f(x))=r.  Never mind. This makes sense. But is my proof for (c) correct?

Comment: I think you've got the order mixed up.  Given $\varepsilon>0$ choose $\delta$ so that $|x-q|<\delta\implies |g(x)-r|<\varepsilon$, by continuity of $g$.  Now argue that for $x$ close to $p$, $f(x)$ is close to $q$, by definition of the limit.